# Problems with importing data set - Can someone help out?

Tags: r, csv, import, dataset

I'm new to R and rn I'm trying to do some exercises in order to get comfortable with using R. Unfortunately I'm already ahving hell of a trouble to import my csv file. Even though the file is completely seperated by commas, R ist not realizing it for every line..
[code_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP85I.png)
Maybe someone of you can tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it.
(Btw: Could you also tell me, why - when importing datasets - the preview is loading endless long? The only way for me to import the data is to cancel the preview and then click on the import buttom in the lower right corner)...
Cheers

As wished here some input from the csv file:

```
{year,month,service,departure_station,arrival_station,journey_time_avg,total_num_trips,num_of_canceled_trains,comment_cancellations,num_late_at_departure,avg_delay_late_at_departure,avg_delay_all_departing,comment_delays_at_departure,num_arriving_late,avg_delay_late_on_arrival,avg_delay_all_arriving,comment_delays_on_arrival,delay_cause_external_cause,delay_cause_rail_infrastructure,delay_cause_traffic_management,delay_cause_rolling_stock,delay_cause_station_management,delay_cause_travelers,num_greater_15_min_late,avg_delay_late_greater_15_min,num_greater_30_min_late,num_greater_60_min_late;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS EST,METZ,85.1337792642,299,0,NA,15,11.55,0.752006688963,NA,17,13.7941176471,0.419843924192,NA,0.25,0,0.166666666667,0.416666666667,0.166666666667,0,6,24.0333333333,1,0;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,REIMS,PARIS EST,47.064516129,218,1,NA,10,14.6533333333,1.26351766513,NA,23,13.5702898551,1.13755760369,NA,0.25,0.375,0.125,0.125,0.0625,0.0625,9,21.4981481481,1,0;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS EST,STRASBOURG,116.234939759,333,1,NA,20,13.6941666667,1.13925702811,NA,19,21.5324561404,1.58639558233,NA,0.214285714286,0.214285714286,0.0714285714286,0.285714285714,0.214285714286,0,14,24.694047619,3,0;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,AVIGNON TGV,161.089583333,481,1,NA,36,20.9884259259,1.40621527778,NA,61,26.5666666667,4.78854166667,NA,0.155172413793,0.120689655172,0.310344827586,0.344827586207,0.0344827586207,0.0344827586207,40,34.0475,21,5;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,BELLEGARDE (AIN),164.452631579,190,0,NA,16,20.9635416667,1.72894736842,NA,38,23.151754386,6.00885964912,NA,0.166666666667,0.25,0.25,0.305555555556,0,0.0277777777778,26,28.4012820513,8,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,BESANCON FRANCHE COMTE TGV,128.521052632,191,1,NA,18,19.9638888889,1.83877192982,NA,18,31.587962963,5.03368421053,NA,0.111111111111,0.111111111111,0.222222222222,0.5,0,0.0555555555556,15,35.7966666667,8,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,CHAMBERY CHALLES LES EAUX,PARIS LYON,183.918269231,208,0,NA,49,12.5193877551,3.81690705128,NA,38,25.9214912281,6.4453525641,NA,0.0588235294118,0.352941176471,0.382352941176,0.176470588235,0.0294117647059,0,31,29.0774193548,11,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,GRENOBLE,186.327102804,216,2,NA,24,20.4701388889,2.21168224299,NA,37,36.6216216216,6.57943925234,NA,0.108108108108,0.189189189189,0.27027027027,0.351351351351,0.0810810810811,0,24,49.6875,13,6;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,LYON PART DIEU,PARIS LYON,121.283333333,661,1,NA,141,13.0839243499,3.89805555556,NA,122,21.3848360656,5.35356060606,NA,0.0490196078431,0.323529411765,0.294117647059,0.186274509804,0.127450980392,0.0196078431373,70,28.0764285714,20,3;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,MACON LOCHE,97.4378109453,201,0,NA,23,18.115942029,2.14170812604,NA,26,25.6634615385,5.1447761194,NA,0,0.173913043478,0.391304347826,0.347826086957,0.0434782608696,0.0434782608696,16,33.8854166667,9,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,MARSEILLE ST CHARLES,198.485981308,429,1,NA,33,23.1353535354,1.6359423676,NA,64,33.41640625,6.76693925234,NA,0.238095238095,0.111111111111,0.269841269841,0.301587301587,0.047619047619,0.031746031746,46,41.6057971014,25,9;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,MONTPELLIER,PARIS LYON,205.816568047,341,3,NA,51,16.8160130719,2.96548323471,NA,67,26.9587064677,5.97608481262,NA,0.209677419355,0.41935483871,0.241935483871,0.0645161290323,0.0161290322581,0.0483870967742,49,32.3683673469,15,4;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS LYON,MULHOUSE VILLE,166.758730159,316,1,NA,39,21.2205128205,2.6344973545,NA,33,29.6878787879,4.17851851852,NA,0.153846153846,0.115384615385,0.192307692308,0.461538461538,0.0384615384615,0.0384615384615,25,35.3573333333,13,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,MULHOUSE VILLE,PARIS LYON,168.713395639,322,1,NA,30,9.86,1.74304257529,NA,24,19.7479166667,2.32481827622,NA,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.05,0.05,10,31.3016666667,2,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,ANGERS SAINT LAUD,90.885,403,3,NA,22,17.3977272727,0.94125,NA,66,22.3633838384,4.78083333333,NA,0.157894736842,0.350877192982,0.280701754386,0.122807017544,0.0350877192982,0.0526315789474,28,38.6345238095,13,4;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,BORDEAUX ST JEAN,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,143.064362336,842,3,NA,135,14.1695061728,2.74819229241,NA,136,22.6240196078,4.99918553834,NA,0.115702479339,0.388429752066,0.231404958678,0.198347107438,0.0413223140496,0.0247933884298,76,30.6280701754,21,4;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,LA ROCHELLE VILLE,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,170.520408163,199,3,NA,1,29,0.265306122449,NA,32,19.3765625,4.91734693878,NA,0.275862068966,0.310344827586,0.241379310345,0.172413793103,0,0,16,26.5708333333,4,1;;;;;;;;
"2017,9,National,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,POITIERS,94.1115789474,479,4,NA,35,13.0576190476,0.911473684211,NA,49,22.3319727891,3.70350877193,""Ce mois-ci, cette OD a été touchée par:";;;;;;;;
Le 17 : Incident caténaire au nord de Bordeaux  (37 TGV ; 382’);;;;;;;
Le 19 : Avarie Matérielle à St Pierre des Corps (15 TGV ; 384’);;;;;;;
Le 20 : Colis suspect à Paris Montparnasse  (17 TGV ; 208’);;;;;;;
Le 25 : Dérangement d’installation Télecom entre Paris et Massy (40 TGV ; 803’);;;;;;;
Le 27 : Rail cassé à Courtalain (100 TGV ; 4112’);;;;;;;
Le 28 : défaillance matérielle en sortie de Paris Montparnasse (22 TGV ;" 395’)"",0.153846153846,0.384615384615,0.102564102564,0.307692307692,0.025641025641,0.025641025641,25,35.48,9,4";;;;;;;
2017,9,National,POITIERS,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,93.6931818182,442,2,NA,72,12.7581018519,2.68045454545,NA,90,16.9022222222,4.59420454545,NA,0.202898550725,0.376811594203,0.231884057971,0.144927536232,0.028985507246400002,0.014492753623200001,37,26.4036036036,8,1;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,RENNES,98.5328836425,597,4,NA,49,17.4928571429,1.55309162451,NA,100,20.88,4.34401349073,NA,0.20253164557,0.278481012658,0.215189873418,0.26582278481,0.0253164556962,0.0126582278481,40,37.675,14,5;;;;;;;;
2017,9,National,VANNES,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,156.027027027,259,0,NA,21,16.0476190476,2.15444015444,NA,49,23.5391156463,6.74118404118,NA,0.15,0.425,0.25,0.125,0,0.05,29,31.4408045977,7,3;;;;;;;;
"2017,9,National,LILLE,MARSEILLE ST CHARLES,300.282758621,146,1,NA,16,14.6302083333,1.94701149425,NA,45,25.6681481481,10.3950574713,""Nombreux colis suspects RYT (03-05-06-07-09-11-12-1726-29) RYT";;;;;;;;
Nombreux colis suspects MVC (07-10-21-27-29) MVC;;;;;;;;
Causes espacement zone SE, avec des trains inter secteurs qui ne dépassent pas les 60% de régularité pour le mois (9866: 16,7%; 9882 : 60%;" 9860: 50% et 9828: 46,7%)--On peut ajouter les 5180 et 5186 qui ne dépassent pas les63% de régularité."",0.243243243243,0.324324324324,0.162162162162,0.189189189189,0,0.0810810810811,45,25.6681481481,12,1";;;;;;
2017,9,International,PARIS EST,FRANCFORT,128.124183007,153,0,NA,25,14.5553333333,2.60740740741,NA,17,27.1823529412,3.04248366013,NA,0.0909090909091,0.363636363636,0.181818181818,0.181818181818,0.181818181818,0,14,30.0785714286,6,0;;;;;;;;
2017,9,International,PARIS LYON,LAUSANNE,219.950952381,141,1,NA,13,22.341025641,2.00273809524,NA,21,32.5150793651,6.2880952381,NA,0.0952380952381,0.190476190476,0.285714285714,0.380952380952,0,0.047619047619,19,34.9377192982,6,2;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,ANGERS SAINT LAUD,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,96.6177777778,467,17,NA,35,15.5580952381,1.98418518519,NA,37,27.8918918919,3.48907407407,NA,0.294117647059,0.294117647059,0.147058823529,0.117647058824,0,0.147058823529,27,33.7512345679,13,3;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,DOUAI,PARIS NORD,79.475,205,5,NA,9,13.1351851852,1.09625,NA,45,14.5159259259,3.57166666667,NA,0.258064516129,0.193548387097,0.387096774194,0.0967741935484,0.0645161290323,0,13,30.1487179487,5,1;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,LYON PART DIEU,LILLE,186.775510204,299,5,NA,148,17.4161036036,9.61507936508,NA,92,30.1836956522,10.9306689342,NA,0.225,0.2125,0.225,0.2125,0.0875,0.0375,73,34.8123287671,22,7;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,MACON LOCHE,PARIS LYON,98.9219512195,210,5,NA,79,12.3293248945,5.93723577236,NA,26,26.1314102564,3.05317073171,NA,0.130434782609,0.304347826087,0.260869565217,0.217391304348,0.0434782608696,0.0434782608696,20,30.3458333333,8,0;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,MARSEILLE ST CHARLES,PARIS LYON,201.419512195,418,8,NA,28,19.0083333333,1.55296747967,NA,48,47.5809027778,4.78670731707,présence de personnes dans les voies + arbre engageant le gabarit + multiples dérangements + balourd tripode sur le 6120 + détresse d'un train de travaux,0.1875,0.208333333333,0.333333333333,0.25,0.0208333333333,0,34,62.3200980392,22,13;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,MARSEILLE ST CHARLES,LILLE,300.356321839,178,4,NA,15,26.2922222222,2.59367816092,NA,48,35.8777777778,11.5889846743,NA,0.217391304348,0.260869565217,0.239130434783,0.173913043478,0.0652173913043,0.0434782608696,48,35.8777777778,14,6;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,NANCY,PARIS EST,93.8413793103,291,1,NA,39,16.5636752137,2.67034482759,NA,39,27.0700854701,2.81879310345,NA,0.235294117647,0.0588235294118,0.441176470588,0.176470588235,0.0294117647059,0.0588235294118,20,43.5566666667,10,3;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS EST,NANCY,95.181184669,289,2,NA,25,22.1993333333,2.11393728223,NA,32,33.9369791667,4.1818815331,NA,0.310344827586,0.0344827586207,0.275862068966,0.310344827586,0.0689655172414,0,22,43.8401515152,13,4;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS LYON,LE CREUSOT MONTCEAU MONTCHANIN,78.815920398,201,0,NA,18,15.9296296296,1.34535655058,NA,19,25.3587719298,2.771973466,NA,0.230769230769,0.384615384615,0.153846153846,0.230769230769,0,0,7,53.8642857143,5,3;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS LYON,MACON LOCHE,95.7926267281,218,1,NA,13,14.0141025641,0.858525345622,NA,18,22.812962963,2.23110599078,NA,0.277777777778,0.277777777778,0,0.444444444444,0,0,10,31.46,6,0;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS LYON,MARSEILLE ST CHARLES,202.905109489,413,2,NA,28,18.7202380952,1.11496350365,NA,45,46.7111111111,6.19188969992,présence de personnes dans les voies + arbre engageant le gabarit + multiples dérangements + alarme incendie sur le 6207,0.113636363636,0.295454545455,0.25,0.340909090909,0,0,34,57.9632352941,19,10;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS LYON,MULHOUSE VILLE,167.604240283,289,6,NA,21,17.4507936508,1.16866902238,NA,46,28.6047101449,6.18722025913,NA,0.157894736842,0.184210526316,0.289473684211,0.289473684211,0.0526315789474,0.0263157894737,32,35.78125,10,4;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS LYON,NICE VILLE,343.278688525,194,11,NA,17,19.6098039216,0.231876138434,NA,28,45.643452381,9.82358834244,présence de personnes dans les voies + arbre engageant le gabarit + multiples dérangements + alarme incendie sur le 6207,0.214285714286,0.285714285714,0.25,0.178571428571,0.0357142857143,0.0357142857143,28,45.643452381,13,6;;;;;;;;
2017,1,International,PARIS LYON,ZURICH,177.990559441,143,0,NA,12,11.6597222222,0.793123543124,NA,22,33.2272727273,6.22948717949,NA,0.0909090909091,0.318181818182,0.272727272727,0.272727272727,0,0.0454545454545,15,42.7333333333,5,2;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,NANTES,139.530737705,510,22,NA,25,18.6686666667,0.954200819672,NA,64,32.2442708333,6.71349043716,NA,0.233333333333,0.283333333333,0.25,0.2,0.0166666666667,0.0166666666667,33,50.9787878788,16,4;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,VANNES,197.253521127,213,0,NA,14,17.7583333333,1.0417057903,NA,29,35.1896551724,5.30516431925,NA,0.36,0.12,0.08,0.32,0.04,0.08,21,43.7857142857,10,4;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS NORD,DOUAI,66.405,202,2,NA,7,13.9095238095,0.601583333333,NA,38,14.1728070175,2.5855,NA,0.25,0.321428571429,0.214285714286,0.0714285714286,0.142857142857,0,10,30.2733333333,3,1;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PARIS NORD,DUNKERQUE,119.682730924,253,4,NA,9,19.6148148148,0.692570281124,NA,20,26.05,2.54417670683,NA,0.45,0.2,0.15,0.2,0,0,17,28.4117647059,5,0;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,PERPIGNAN,PARIS LYON,302.318471338,160,3,NA,22,15.0257575758,2.48609341826,NA,22,52.8840909091,6.1872611465,présence de personnes dans les voies + arbre engageant le gabarit + multiples dérangements + balourd tripode sur le 6120 + détresse d'un train de travaux,0.117647058824,0.235294117647,0.294117647059,0.294117647059,0.0588235294118,0,22,52.8840909091,12,5;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,RENNES,LYON PART DIEU,259.801980198,105,4,NA,8,15.875,1.87128712871,NA,19,39.8280701754,6.83894389439,NA,0.222222222222,0.444444444444,0.166666666667,0.166666666667,0,0,19,39.8280701754,10,4;;;;;;;;
2017,1,National,SAINT ETIENNE CHATEAUCREUX,PARIS LYON,168.375,115,3,NA,1,21.8,-0.146875,NA,14,19.25,2.69717261905,NA,0.444444444444,0.111111111111,0.333333333333,0.111111111111,0,0,9,23.1444444444,1,0;;;;;;;;
"2017,1,National,ST PIERRE DES CORPS,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,63.1299303944,434,3,NA,66,18.1275252525,3.64605568445,NA,88,16.8501893939,4.01040216551,""Le 1er janvier : accident de personne à Châtellerault (44 TGV "; 2744’);;;;;;;
Le 2 : Avarie sur le pantographe d’un TER à Paris Montparnasse (29 TGV ; 329’);;;;;;;
Le 4 : Choc anormal sur la ligne à grande vitesse (33 TGV ; 814’);;;;;;;
Le 4 : Dérangement d’un appareil de voie à Paris Montparnasse (24 TGV ; 475’);;;;;;;
Le 11 : Colis suspect à Ruffec (14 TGV ; 235’);;;;;;;
Le 17 : Rail cassé à Massy (31 TGV ; 573’);;;;;;;
Le 18 : Dérangement d’installation suite à travaux non conformes à Angoulême (19 TGV ;" 260’)"",0.224137931034,0.344827586207,0.172413793103,0.206896551724,0,0.051724137931,26,36.903846153800004,8,5";;;;;;;
2017,1,National,VALENCE ALIXAN TGV,PARIS LYON,132.636363636,273,9,NA,62,13.1685483871,3.87203282828,NA,31,30.5430107527,1.75542929293,NA,0.217391304348,0.260869565217,0.173913043478,0.347826086957,0,0,26,34,11,2;;;;;;;;
2017,7,National,PARIS LYON,DIJON VILLE,95.8430913349,429,2,NA,64,25.8125,3.97658079625,NA,63,27.8253968254,4.14988290398,heurt d'une personne par un Transilien à Maisons-Alfort +  dérangement de signalisation à Vaux-en-Pré + alarme incendie et absence d'alimentation sur le 6145 à Pasilly,0.211538461538,0,0.0961538461538,0.634615384615,0.0384615384615,0.0192307692308,41,36.7715447,18,6;;;;;;;;
2017,7,National,PARIS LYON,LE CREUSOT MONTCEAU MONTCHANIN,78.6262135922,206,0,NA,20,12.6,1.21844660194,NA,41,11.0487804878,2.48058252427,NA,0.275862068966,0.206896551724,0.206896551724,0.241379310345,0,0.0689655172414,7,26.4809524,2,0;;;;;;;;
2017,7,National,PARIS LYON,NICE VILLE,341.674911661,287,4,NA,54,21.2407407407,4.07067137809,NA,88,39.7840909091,15.2650176678,heurt d'une personne par un Transilien à Maisons-Alfort + dérangement de signalisation à Chandieu-Tousssieu + mutiples incendies vers Aix-en-Provence + alarme incendie et absence d'alimentation sur le 6145 à Pasilly + caténaire endommagée entre Toulon et La Garde,0.302325581395,0.116279069767,0.267441860465,0.174418604651,0.093023255814,0.046511627907,88,39.769697,54,14;;;;;;;;
2017,7,National,PARIS LYON,PERPIGNAN,305.741463415,205,0,NA,36,26.1388888889,4.42926829268,NA,44,52.5227272727,13.2341463415,NA,0.272727272727,0.318181818182,0.113636363636,0.272727272727,0.0227272727273,0,44,52.5185606,26,12;;;;;;;;
2017,7,National,PERPIGNAN,PARIS LYON,306.080851064,235,0,NA,43,14.6046511628,3.16170212766,NA,47,43.4893617021,9.80425531915,heurt d'une personne par un Transilien à Maisons-Alfort +  dérangement de signalisation à Vaux-en-Pré + incendie aux abords des voies entre Avignon et Nîmes + dérangement d'aiguille à Vestric,0.439024390244,0.0243902439024,0.317073170732,0.0975609756098,0,0.121951219512,47,43.5255319,22,8;;;;;;;;
"2017,7,National,BORDEAUX ST JEAN,PARIS MONTPARNASSE,143.722222222,776,20,NA,203,18.4532019704,5.53174603175,NA,195,36.1692307692,10.8399470899,""Ce mois-ci, l'OD a été touchée par: _x000D_";;;;;;;;
Le 7 : Défaillance matérielle à la sortie de la gare de Paris Montparnasse (87 TGV ; 2202’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
Le 11 : Divergence entre les équipements au sol et les TGV en circulation sur la grande ceinture parisienne (36 TGV ; 1034’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
Le 13 : Dérangement d’aiguille sur le tronc commun des lignes grandes vitesse à St Arnoult (19 TGV ; 289’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
Le 13 : Défaut d’alimentation électrique à la sortie de la gare de Paris Montparnasse (30 TGV ; 422’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
Le 17 : Rupture caténaire en gare de Paris Montparnasse (75 TGV ; 4801’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
Le 19 : Dérangement d’installation télécom sur la nouvelle ligne grande vitesse vers Bordeaux (22 TGV ; 543’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
Le 25 : Dérangement d’installation sur la nouvelle ligne grande vitesse vers Bordeaux (21 TGV ; 482’)_x000D_;;;;;;;
}
```

I have no clue what to try, so therefore I'm hoping for some guidance ehre from the experienced community :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, David S.! There's little we can do with just an image of a sample of data. To be able to help most, can you please [edit] your question and add enough sample from the raw `.csv` file (using `notepad.exe` to edit and copy) and paste into your question in a [code block]?

Comment: Thank you for responding! Is it better now that I've added a part of the csv file from the editor?

Comment: Hi David! I think the quotation marks in your dataset ruin reading in the data correctly. Everything between quotation marks will be seen as one entry. You either have to clean it up beforehand, or do data cleaning afterwards. For the last option, you would need some string manipulation

Comment: The curly braces might be sabotaging your column names. And you have some embedded quotes that might be causing large blobs of data to be missed. Quotes need to be escaped or removed. You might have some further problems if the semicolons are meaningful as item separators.

Comment: Whereever you got that data, I suggest you go back to them and ask what format they intend to use: it looks as if it _might_ be comma-delimited embedded within semi-colon-delimited, but with inconsistent quoting and a distracting wrap in `{`-braces. Is it possible to fix this? Perhaps, but it will be full of so many fragile hacks that I'm not even confident it'll work with larger/real data. I suggest you fix the source before trying to import it.

Comment: Thanks guys - this was a starter task at university in order to get familiar with R, but I already struggled with importing the dataset. I guess I'll ask the prof about that, it seems, that the dataset must be cleaned as you said